# Cannot parse date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse the date from a certificate to verify its validity and this error is shown:

Unparseable date: "Mon Dec 05 09:47:18 CST 2011"

The SimpleFormat I'm currently using is:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE mmm dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(inputDate);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `MMM` instead of `mmm` for the month name part. Also check which locale you're using, as obviously different locales have different month and day names.